# Tramp `find-dired`: wrong type argument error

Tags: tramp, find-dired

If i use `find-dired` in a remote directory (from Tramp) then I get a `wrong type argument: processp, nil` error.

It works on a local dir.

All I pass to `find` is '-iname "*blah*"'.

```
/sftp:andreaz@10.0.0.99:/home/andreaz/files/:

find . \( -name "*blah*" \) -exec ls -ld \{\} \;
```

Answer (score 2):

`sftp` is implemented in Tramp by GVFS, so it doesn't support remote processes. You must use a Tramp method like `ssh` or `scp`.